# Using the Where statement in SQL

Tags: select, join, where-clause

How can I Select the idR and recipeTitle if ingrDesc is "cumin" 
this is what I have:

- Recipe = (idR, recipeTitle, prepText, cuisineType, mealType)
- Ingredient = (idI, ingrDesc)
- RecipIngr = (idR*, idI*)

  ```
  SELECT idR, recipeTitle 
  FROM Recipe
  JOIN Ingredient
  WHERE ingrDesc='cumin'
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing your table structure, any guess would be somewhat random.  Here's a random guess.  I guess that Ingredient has a foreign key relating it to Recipe.  I'll call that key RecipeId.

```
SELECT idR, recipeTitle 
FROM Recipe r
INNER JOIN Ingredient i
ON r.idR = i.RecipeId
WHERE ingrDesc='cumin'
```